# OpenXml SpreadsheetDocument SaveAs() produces corrupted document - why?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

This dead-simple code creates a file that Excel won't open.
How could this be failing?

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"c:\dir\src.xlsx", true))
{
  doc.SaveAs(@"c:\dir\saved.xlsx");
}
```

Notes:

- Excel won't open saved.xlsx
- src.xlsx is known to exist and be valid (Excel opens it no problem)
- saved.xlsx is indeed produced, though it's about 500 bytes smaller than src.xlsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant this error:
[Stop debugging before opening the "saved.xlsx" file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIPFP.png)

I've checked. It works correctly:
[Output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/305Nt.png)

Comment: The issue was caused by having having src.xlsx open in Excel while accessing it via OpenXml

Comment: Right. The soluation is to stop debugging or close the Excel program during the running.